# I am trying to convert rows into columns using pivot but its not letting me to aggregate over two different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table:

```
Day CheckIn CheckOut Employee Id
------------------------------------
Sun 09:00   10:00     1
Sun 11:00   13:00     1
Mon 08:00   11:00     1
Mon 14:00   16:00     1
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
SunCheckIn SunCheckOut MonCheckIn MonCheckOut
-----------------------------------------------------
09:00      10:00        08:00      11:00
11:00      13:00        14:00      16:00
```

I tried using joins but nothing helps. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Hello Saranya. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

Your desired output is not well suited for SQL.  You *can* produce it, but you essentially have two lists in the columns.  Phrased another way, the rows don't really mean anything.

You can get it by using `row_number()` to enumerate the rows and then using conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when day = 'Sun' then CheckIn end) as SunCheckIn,
       max(case when day = 'Sun' then CheckOut end) as SunCheckOut,
       max(case when day = 'Mon' then CheckIn end) as MonCheckIn,
       max(case when day = 'Mon' then CheckOut end) as MonCheckOut       
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by day order by checkin) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write as:

```
;with CTE as
(select Day,CheckIn,CheckOut, EmployeeId,
Row_Number() over ( partition by Day,EmployeeId order by CheckIn,CheckOut) as rownum
from test 
)
select T.EmployeeId,
       T.CheckIn as 'SunCheckIn' , 
       T.CheckOut as 'SunCheckOut' , 
       T1.CheckIn as 'MonCheckIn',
       T1.CheckOut as 'MonCheckOut'
from CTE as T
Left join CTE as T1 on T.EmployeeId = T1.EmployeeId
and T.rownum = T1.rownum and T.Day <> T1.Day and T1.Day = 'Mon'
where T.Day = 'Sun'
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/NLETL78586)</kbd>